# For JSON from mongodb how to extract ObjectID and then time stamp from that using java?

Tags: java, mongodb

My code is

```
ClientRequest request1 = new ClientRequest(url);
request1.accept("application/json");
ClientResponse<String> response1 = request1.get(String.class);
System.out.println(response1);

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    new ByteArrayInputStream(response1.getEntity().getBytes())));

String output=null;
while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

I need to extract just Object ID from Output and then get the timestamp from it.

Output:

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5252e015b11ce2799f84334d"), 
  "ConductivityChangeAlarm" : "1", 
  "LevelAlarm" : "1", 
  "WaterTankLevel" : "100cm", 
  "DeviceIndicator" : "1", 
  "HighPresuurePump" : "1", 
  "LowPressureAlarm" : "0", 
  "PremeateFlowRateDisplay" : "5gpm", 
  "CartridgeFilterPressureDropIncrease" : "0", 
  "RawWaterFlowRate" : "20gpm", 
  "TotaliseronHMI" : "1", 
  "FeedConductivityDisplay" : "500μS", 
  "RecirculationFlowRate" : "150gpd", 
  "HighPressureDisplay" : "32psi" 
}
```

Comment: sorry.. i had missed that.. just edited it...

Comment: @user2572739 I can't see timestamp in the json output you posted.

Comment: we can get time from objectId right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is create `import org.json.JSONObject` (`JSONObject`) from String and manipulate it.

```
String SampleJSON = "{ \"_id\" : ObjectId(\"5252e015b11ce2799f84334d\")}";
JSONObject resultObject = new JSONObject(SampleJSON);
String value_ID = resultObject.get("_id").toString();
/* Manipulate as you want. Like remove () and all */
System.out.println(value_ID);
```